# How to add additional condition to Laravel 6 Auth attempt() method?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-6, guard

I'm using Larvel 6

I want to add this feature to my app:

The app receives User's mobile number, then generates a `mobile_number_verification_code` like `145787` and updates user's table! then the generated code will be sent as SMS for user! and he/she enters the code to login!

**Notice:** the code can be used **just 2 minutes** after the generation time

this will be the `User` model

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('username')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile_number')->unique()->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile_number_verification_code')->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile_number_verification_code_expires_at')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('mobile_number_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

I want to use the Laravel default auth way, so I can use this code for attempt to login:

```
/**
 * Attempt to log the user into the application.
 *
 * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
 * @return bool
 */
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    return $this->guard('users')->attempt(
        [
            'mobile_number' => '9128889966', // the mobile number
            'mobile_number_verification_code' => '145787' // the code which user has received
        ]
        , $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

everything seems alright but one important point is missed:
*the code can be used **just 2 minutes** after the generation time*

How can I check the code is expired or not?
I know that I can check it after user login, then if the code is expired, use `Auth::logout();`  to logout him/her! but is it the best way?
It is not better to edit the `attempt()` method?

Comment: Is the `mobile_number_verification_code` stored in the users table?

Comment: @Rwd yes, is there any problem?

Comment: How would you go about checking if it has expired? Do you also have a timestamp/datetime column for when the code was created?

Comment: @Rwd I fill mobile_number_verification_code_expires_at with unix timestamp (biginteger) when I generate the code!

Comment: Are you using JWT driver?

Comment: @Viney no, I'm using eloquent

Answer (score 2):

You can check expiration datetime on `attemptLogin` method of your `LoginController` like this:

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    //...

    /**
     * Attempt to log the user into the application.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
    {
        return \App\User::where('mobile_number', $request->mobile_number)
            ->whereDate('mobile_number_verification_code_expires_at', '>=', now())
            ->exists()
            && $this->guard()->attempt([
                'mobile_number' => $request->mobile_number
                'mobile_number_verification_code' => $request->mobile_number_verification_code
            ], $request->filled('remember')
    );
}
```

Another way is to define a custom `UserProvider` that implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider` interface or extends `Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider` and override `validateCredentials` and/or `retrieveByCredentials` methods. Then register your customized `UserProvider` and set it as custom driver on `config/auth.php` file. See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) form more info about this.

Comment: thanks for your help, this seems good but as you know there are 2 database requests in this way: the first one for \App\User::where and the second one for attempt() method! I want to be sure to use the way with the best performance! do you think this answer is the best one?

Comment: @soheilyo I've updated my answer and added an alternative but more complicated way. If you want to customize the code less as possible, I think it's the simplest way. but if you want best performance you have to define your custom `UserProvider` as I said.

Comment: How can we add NOT and OR condition in the login auth query? Kindly suggest. Thanks.